# What is an autoregressive synchronous panel model in structural equation modeling (SEM)?

Tags: panel-data, structural-equation-modeling, autoregressive

I am reading a paper on the use of social networks and political participation that uses SEM for data analysis ([Halpern, Valenzuela, & Katz, 2017](http://Halpern,%20D.,%20Valenzuela,%20S.,%20&%20Katz,%20J.%20E.%20(2017))). The authors employ a two-wave panel survey to collect their data and then they say this...:

> We used autoregressive synchronous panel models, where change over time is estimated by regressing wave-2 variables on their wave-1 values. This approach sets a stringent test because it considers both temporal stability and covariance of key endogenous variables.

I have never heard of "autoregressive synchronous panel models" and Googling the term did not help. Would that mean that paths are estimated between the variables at the same time points and cross-lagged effects omitted? But then how does one identify the model given that it will be non-recursive (given there'd be synchronous reciprocal paths between two variables and/or both a synchronous path and correlated disturbance terms between two variables).

And what is the point/advantage of such an approach compared to a cross-lagged model? I am quite familiar with the basic concepts and workflows of SEM but I've barely heard of this approach. The models' illustrations look like this:
[an example of a simple model in the paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UI9sC.png)

So, my questions are:

1) What is a autoregressive synchronous panel model and how do you create one in Amos/SPSS/R/Python? Is it even possible with observed variables (no latent variables with multiple indicators).

2) What are the advantages of this method compared to cross-lagged models?

Thank you for reading and potentially answering my questions.

References:

Halpern, D., Valenzuela, S., & Katz, J. E. (2017). We face, I tweet: How different social media influence political participation through collective and internal efficacy. Journal of Computer-Mediated Communication, 22(6), 320-336.

Comment: That looks like what I'd call a cross-lagged model.

Comment: Ah @JeremyMiles, thanks again for answering another one of my questions. Indeed, it does look like a cross-lagged model to me, too - just with synchronous correlations present. The only problem with that is that there is no way it would be identified with only observed variables present (and no "instrument" variables). Especially if we also add all the cross-lagged paths, then there's certainly not enough unique data. Am I wrong to assume that? 
Additionally, I can't see a reason to use this approach to find evidence for causal relationships.

*I edited my question to reflect these concerns

Comment: The model is just-identified with all paths (has zero df), you typically add synchronous correlations in cross-lagged models. SEM is just regression, it's no better (and no worse) at finding causal relationships. The advantage is that you are incorporating time (there's a book by David Kenny called "Correlation and causality" that discusses this. You can download from: http://davidakenny.net/doc/cc_v1.pdf